# Truncate text but keep html in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, substring, truncate, substr

I am printing a string `<a href="..">some text</a>, <a href="..">some other text</a>`.

I want to truncate the visible text, but keeping the link.

If I just did a naïve substring, I would mess up the html.

I want to make sure that only 100 characters are shown, but if the last part of the string is, for instance, `<a hre`, then this should be stripped as well.

## Edit

I have tried

```
arr = ['some text', 'some other text', 'some third text'];
output = arr.map(el => '<a href="#">' + el + '</a>').join(', ');

// print
console.log(output.substr(0, 20))
```

but this will cut off the html and output

```
<a href="#">some tex
```

But I want it to count the number of shown characters instead of how many characters were used to show the output.

So if the shown output is `some text, some other text, some third text`, I want it to cut it off at character 20 in the output text rather than character 20 in the html output.

Comment: Recommend showing what you've tried so far, as it stands you are simply asking us to write you code.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: You're going to have to do the character count and truncation before mapping each value  in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Set `textContent` of elements to anything you want:

```js
(function() {
  var links = document.getElementsByClassName("link");
  for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].textContent = "Link text changed";
  }
})();
```

```html
<a class="link" href="http://stackexchange.com">Stack Exchange</a>
<a class="link" href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with simple CSS.

```js
  var paragraph = document.querySelector('p#before');

  document.querySelector('p#after-text').innerHTML = truncateTEXT(paragraph, 20, true);
  document.querySelector('p#after-html').innerHTML = truncateHTML(paragraph, 20, true);

  function truncateHTML(html, limit, dots) {
    holdCounter = false;
    truncatedHTML = '';
    html = paragraph.innerHTML;

    for(index = 0; index < html.length; index++) {
      if(!limit) {
        break;
      }
      if(html[index] == '<') {
        holdCounter = true;
      }
      if(!holdCounter) {
        limit--;
      }
      if(html[index] == '>') {
        holdCounter = false;
      }
      truncatedHTML += html[index];
    }
    truncatedHTML = correctHTML(truncatedHTML);
    if(dots) {
      truncatedHTML = truncatedHTML + '...';
    }
    return truncatedHTML;
  }


  function truncateTEXT(string, limit, dots) {
    string = string.innerText;
    if(string.length > limit) {
      return string.substring(0, limit) + (dots ? '...' : '');
    } else {
      return string;
    }
  }

  function correctHTML(html){
    container = document.createElement('div');
    container.innerHTML = html

    return container.innerHTML;
  }
```

```html
<p id="before"><a href="#">Lorem</a> <strong>ipsum</strong> <a href="#">dolor</a> <strong>sit</strong> <a href="#">amet</a> <strong>consectetur</strong> <a href="#">adipiscing</a> <strong>elit</strong></p>
<p id="after-text"></p>
<p id="after-html"></p>
```

Comment: I don't think is what OP wants he want to truncate the whole text in your case paragraph not the link. And if link is the last in should be truncated.

Comment: Well, you're right. I've write some simple script and hope to help with it.